# Check if an axis aligned bounding box is inside view frustum

Tags: java, math, 3d, geometry, frustum

Lets say that my Frustum consists of 6 planes and each of these planes has the following variables:

```
Vector3f tl;    // top left
Vector3f tr;    // top right
Vector3f bl;    // bottom left
Vector3f br;    // bottom right
Vector3f n;     // normal
```

Now I have an axis aligned bounding box for every entity on my scene.
And I want to check if the bounding box is inside the view frustum.
How would I do that?
I don't understand the math behind that.

Answer (score 2):

Your objects are convex polyhedrons, so you can use Separating Axes Theorem ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), [article](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf)).

For AABB axes are rather simple ([arbitrary found example](https://gist.github.com/Kinwailo/d9a07f98d8511206182e50acda4fbc9b) shows using of OX, OY, OZ axes)

Comment: Yes I came accross this. the problem is that I cannot find a SIMPLE explaination. I do not understand math. especially not when everyone uses symbols that I've never seen before or a short form of writing which confuses me even more.

Comment: @RalleYTN why do you *need* a simple explanation? If you don't understand the algebra, just copy the code and move onto more interesting stuff. This is a widely implemented feature and there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Try to find SAT descriptions in game development field - some articles might be quite simple (while understanding of vector math is necessary in any case). https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169

Comment: @MBo why do I need 2 vectors (mins, maxs) in the arbitary found example?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Because I want to understand how it works.

Comment: @RalleYTN In that case you should read some algebra and game math books before attempting to understand an algorithm such as this. Sometimes it might be impossible to simplify a description any further without omitting important details.

Comment: As far as I understand, `mins, maxs` are two opposite vertices of AABB